# Trouble integrating EnhancedListView and SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to integrate the above mentioned widgets. They seem to be interfering with each other. If I swipe and then scroll down, the list view item doesn't return to the original x position when I let go. Anyone know what could be the issue ?